# AWS Glue: How to connect oracle db using JDBC

Tags: oracle, apache-spark, jdbc, aws-glue

When I'm trying to connect to external Oracle DB from AWS Glue using JDBC getting below errors. Could some one help on this issue?

Driver code using is below:

```
test_df = spark.read.format('jdbc').options(url='jdbc:oracle:thin:username/password@//myhostname:1521/servicename',     dbtable="test", driver='oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver').load()
```

Errors logs are below:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o65.load.
: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Unknown host specified at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:743)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:666)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:566)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Thanks, Srini

Comment: Run and display result `ping myhostname` or `nslookup myhostname`

Comment: From my local pc able to ping the host, i'm getting response. I'm able to connect to the host using mentioned driver from local.    But, same driver code i'm trying to run in AWS Glue, but i'm seeing the above mentioned errors.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you can't resolve the hostname you specify in to the command. Check this line:

`: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error:`**`Unknown host`**`specified at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:743)`

You can use `nslookup` or `dig` command to check if the hostname is resolved like:

```
nslookup hostname

dig hostname
```

If you do not get IP as answer please correct you hostname, `/etc/hosts` record or DNS record

All those tests and updates need to be run on the host where your code is running!

Edit1: If you do not have control on the host where your code is running you can:

1. use FQDN of your host
2. Use IP address instead of hostname (very bad advise, use it as temporary workaround)

Comment: How can i run the above recommended commands from aws ?  pls help

Comment: Check my updated answer. And please update your question with information where the database is located and where your code run.

Comment: how to get FQDN ?  i dont have control over it.  my host name is like this :                    
    bmc-2uccetdb-scaa.itdglbl.local

Comment: You must provide full access to this host from the host where code run. Please check this page: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e47689/app_port.htm#LADBI1403

Comment: It looks like host is already have full access, already we are accessing same host from AWS Lambda functions. There no issue.  We are getting issue here in AWS Glue only. May be any change in the above mentioned driver works ?

Comment: For me the hostname you provide ( bmc-2uccetdb-scaa.itdglbl.local) is not resolved via internet. So IMHO you should provide to AWS Glue hostname which is resolvable

Comment: sorry to disturb, but how come aws lambda function can able to access same host?  In the above host, because of security reason i modified some text before sharing the host name.

Comment: Are those hosts in to the same region? Do you have some network filters on the DB host? Please update your question with all this information

Comment: ok, i'll check with my dba and come back to you by eod. thank u so much.

Comment: As per dba, host and port has full access. And it is on cluster, hence i can try with a specific ip. already i'm using a fqdn.

Comment: Are you sure hostname is resolved from internet? You can check for example with this web page: https://whatismyipaddress.com/hostname-ip

Comment: Just now checked my host, the link did not return anything. But same host we were able to access successfully from aws lambda functions and configured under 
 "aws glue connecions". Problem is coming now only when i am creating glue etl job and trying to call the above connection string.

Comment: Seems the problem is on your site. Please update the hostname to be clearly visible/resolvable via internet